# Django form and angular router ui

Tags: django, angularjs, django-forms, angular-ui-router

I've made a django form to edit values in a module and it is working ok in a single page, not problem so far.

The problem arise when I want to use that form in a state. Currently, I'm using Angular ui- router to display states in a navigation bar. When I click on the "save button" the post action is not being received by the django form. 
It's like that I have to route the post method to pass the values first into angular and then into the form(backend).

Any help is appreciated.

Check my code:

**views.py**

```
def InstitutionDetailView(request):
    client = get_object_or_404(ClientProfile, user=request.user)
    institution = Institution.objects.get_or_create(client=client.id)[0]

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = EditDetailsForm(request.POST, instance = institution)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return  render_to_response('account/client/details.html', 
                {'form': form, 'institution':institution}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = EditDetailsForm(instance = institution)

    return render_to_response('account/client/details.html', 
        {'form': form, 'institution':institution}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
 url(r'^user/client/details.html', auth(views.InstitutionDetailView), name="institution_edit_details"),
```

**details.html**

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('account.client', ['ui.router', 'ngTable'])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $interpolateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      //allow django templates and singular to co-exist
      $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
      $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');

      $urlRouterProvider
      .when('/institution','/institution/details')
      .otherwise('/home');

      $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'client/dashboard.html'
      })
      .state('institution', {
        url: '/institution',
        templateUrl: 'client/institution/'
      })
      .state('institution.details', {
        url: '/details',
        templateUrl: 'client/details.html'
      });

    })
```

Comment: "post action is not being received by the django form" - do you mean problem with the data being sent at all or form invalidity? Are you able to dump any data from request.POST? Does it look somehow correct?

Comment: @tttomekkk when I click on submit button, the view is not identifying any request.post, is like the form was not sending any post request. That only is happening when the page(details.html) is called by the state(app.js). However, when I go directly to the page it works properly, the view can identify the request.post and is able to update the data.